# Selenium IDE - Waiting for modal to disappear

Tags: modal-dialog, selenium-ide

How can I have Selenium IDE to wait for a modal layer to disappear before continuing to fill in the form and click on the button to move to the next step?

Comment: Will modal layer displays immediately after page loaded? do you get the modal layer everytime page loaded?

Comment: Yes the modal will display immediately after page load. The problem is that there are multiple panels in hidden DIVs that will be displayed when clicking  the "continue" button. But when i.e. moving from DIV1 to DIV2 and filling DIV2:input1, DIV2:input2, etc. while the modal overlay will finish loading, those field are then reset! - Unfortunately I can't change the javascript behaviour. That was to make sure in the next Tab you were not going to have pre filled fields. So I really have to wait for the modal to disappear.

Comment: waitForElementNotPresent? WaitForElementNotVisible? I'd try either of those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems perfect use case for either waitForElementNotPresent or WaitForElementNotVisible. Both of those will wait up until the default timeout for the elements to no longer be seen on the screen.

You could use Pause but that is almost NEVER the right answer because waitFor's will only take the amount of time needed up to the timeout. Pause will ALWAYS wait the full time, which is bad.

Comment: I would agree with you 100% but it looks like "pause" is the only thing that works. In the mean time I abandoned the Selenium IDE to use BeHat + Mink. Looks like more reliable. Thank you.

Comment: If a pause works than it's just a matter of waiting for the right thing.

Comment: For those of you who couldn't find `waitForElementNotVisible`, try `waitForNotVisible` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> c# code

I had the same problem and this code is working for me since 6+ months, no more crash.

```
 public static void WaitForModal(this IWebDriver driver)
    {
        wait.Until<IWebDriver>((d) =>
        {
            if (driver.FindElements(By.ClassName("modal-backdrop")).Count == 0)
            {
                return driver;
            }
            return null;
        });
    }
```

It waits until it finds no more `IWebElement` that have a `class` of "modal-backdrop".

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34679990/selenium-ide-waiting-for-modal-to-disappear/42505796#42505796) of [Happy Bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2058019/happy-bird) (thanks a lot, have no access to up-vote yet) is working perfect in java for me as well and saved me a lot of time:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(getWebDriver(), 10);
wait.until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
                    public Boolean apply(WebDriver driver) {                
                        return  getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'modal-backdrop')]")).size() == 0;                   
                    }
                });
```